# Django Rest Framework com Imagens

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Bom ainda estou estudando está framework, pesquisei um pouco tentei algumas formas porém não funcionaram.

#### Erro:

> 'UnboundLocalError at /api/servicos/1/ local variable 'Servico'
> referenced before assignment'

#### Codigo:

**Serializer**

```
from .models import Servico
from rest_framework import serializers

class ServicoSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    imagem = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, use_url=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Servico
        depth = 1
        fields = '__all__'
```

**Model**

```
from django.db import models

def upload_location(instance, filename):
    return "%s/%s" %(instance.id, filename)

class Servico(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField(max_length = 120, verbose_name='Servico')
    valor = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    descricao = models.TextField(verbose_name='descricao', null=True)
    jornada = models.CharField(max_length = 120, verbose_name='jornada')
    imagem = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_location ,null=True,blank=True,
        width_field="width_field",
        height_field="height_field")
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**View**

```
class ServicoView(APIView):
     serializer_class = ServicoSerializer

     def get(self, request, pk, format=None):
         Servico = Servico.objects.get(pk=pk)
         serializer = self.serializer_class(Servico)
         return Response(serializer.data)

    def put(self, request, pk, format=None):
        Servico = Servico.objects.get(pk=pk)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(Servico, data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    def delete(self, request, pk, format=None):
        Servico = Servico.objects.get(pk=pk)
        Servico.delete()
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pelo que vejo no do código que você colocou do `view.py`, você está usando o model `Servico` mas ao mesmo tempo criando uma variável com o mesmo nome `Servico`.